# How can I restore system files that were accidentally deleted in /usr/share and /var/lib/dpkg?

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, files, dpkg, system

So ya, earlier today I accidentally ran a

```
rm -rf /usr/share
```

and let it run for about 15 seconds. And then in trying to fix the error I went ahead and uninstalled all of my desktops and a bunch of other files including /var/lib/dpkg.

I still haven't had any luck having these files restored. Is there anything else I can do other than reinstalling the OS?

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a couple months late but for dpkg I was able to get everything running again by finding the appropriate dpkg file for me that was the file from here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/dpkg
I chose the appropriate .deb file for me (my computer runs on amd64)

I clicked to download it, then clicked save file (The software-center won't work without dpkg). Once downloaded I clicked on the .deb file and opened it and then extracted it to a folder I called Dpkg (of course you can call it whatever you want).

For whatever reason I was having trouble copying the executables to the correct place so I just moved them one at a time. I moved all of the executables out of the folder titled usr/bin into /usr/bin, for example

```
    cd /home/jeremie/Downloads/Dpkg/usr/bin 
    sudo mv dpkg /usr/bin
    sudo mv dpkg-deb /usr/bin
```

and so on.
After moving all of the executables out of that folder I still ran into a problem with the start-stop-daemon so I had to move that from the sbin folder

```
    cd /home/jeremie/Downloads/Dpkg/sbin 
    sudo mv start-stop-daemon /sbin
```

Finally I ran:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```

And voila dpkg was working.